# Is there a 5-regular graph of order 7?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

How can I decide  if there is  a 5-regular graph of order 7?

Some hints or tips would be appreciated. This question arises in studying for a graph theory course.

Comment: Given a $5$-regular graph of order $7$, how many edges would it have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to have such a graph. More generally, it is not possible to have a $d$-regular graph on $n$ vertices for $d$ and $n$ odd.

To see this recall (or convince yourself) that for $e$ the number of edges in a $d$-regular graph on $n$ vertices you have $2e=nd$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $G$ is a $5$-regular graph of order $7$. Let $\bar G$ be the *complementary* graph: same vertices, but two vertices are joined by an edge in $\bar G$ just in case they are **not** joined by an edge in $G$. Can you see that $\bar G$ is a $1$-regular graph of order $7$? Is that possible? Try to draw it.

Comment: you means it's not possivble?

Comment: @MichleJordan: Do you have an opinion of your own on this matter, or are you just going to believe whatever I tell you?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Do you know a theorem that says something about the number of vertices of odd degree?